# How to specify spring data jpa request to load collection of entity properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I use spring data JPA. I need in my repository request to load only collection of concrete properties *colors*:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT cd.color FROM CalendarDetails cd where cd.userCalendar.userId = :userId")
List<String> findCalendarColorsByUserWithDuplicates(@Param("userId") Long userId);
```

Provided solution works correctly.

I want simplify it using spring approach to load collection of the repository objects I'd use (repository `public interface CalendarDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<CalendarDetails, Long>`):

```
List<CalendarDetails> findByUserCalendarUserId(@Param("userId") Long userId);
```

But I need collection of colors! Trying

```
List<String> findColorByUserCalendarUserId(Long userId);
```

I get collection of `CalendarDetails`

Is it possible to improve my last request following spring data approaches to load list of colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try special Projection mechanisms that Spring Data provides. It will allow you not only to optimize your queries but also to make it with pure java without using @Query.

There are a lot of ways to
[make it](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections), but I would recommend the following.
You add an interface that contains getters for the properties that you need to take from entity:

```
public interface ColorOnly {
    String getColor();
}
```

Then you return the list of this interface' objects:

```
List<ColorOnly> findColorByUserCalendarUserId(Long userId);
```

To use the colours from the interface, you just invoke getColor method. You may consider simplifying it with Java 8 streams and map conversions. BTW, this one will only query colour. No other fields will be included into the query Hibernate produces.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add **All**

`findAllByUserCalendarUserId(Long userId);`

BTW, IntelliJ IDEA provide very deep support of JPA repositories, so it's prevent a lot of possible issues when you create queries like this one

Comment: Issue is not with single object result. the result is collection but not expected entity property. But nice try :)

Comment: in this case you should call whole object, you can't query just one field without custom ``@Query``